# EIP712 checks chainID while EIP155 includes chainID info in the signature?

Tags: solidity, eip712

Many contracts implementing EIP712 include chainID info in the domain separators, while after EIP155, most signatures already contain chainID. Do the such domain separators mainly check that old signatures that do not implement EIP155 are not replayed?

Answer (score 0):

[EIP-155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155) applies to public transactions, while [EIP-712](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-712) applies to signed data, which can be the data inside a transaction but not the transaction itself.

EIP-155 ensures that a signed Ethereum transaction cannot be replayed on Ethereum Classic, for example. EIP-712 try to ensure that your signed data cannot be reused on the same application.

While very similar, they do not serve the same purpose.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: I mean, what you are describing is not different from what I was. The EIP155 signatures already contain chainID info against replays. The data for EIP712 is signed, so including the chainID info in the data itself or not doesn't matter. For example, the signed hash for EIP712 --> address signer = ECDSA.recover(hash, v, r, s);, the v value is there.

Comment: "EIP-712 try to ensure that your signed data cannot be reused on the same application." In such EIP712 compatible contracts, they usually hash 'nonce' of users for this, hashing 'chainID' doesn't really matter for whether it can be used for the same application.

Comment: 'The data for EIP712 is signed, so including the chainID info in the data itself or not doesn't matter.' that's not necessarily true, you could send me a signed message that I will send to a smart contract to do something on your behalf. In that case, I would have signed the transaction that includes a message that you signed, EIP-155 protects against tx replay, and EIP-712 protects against message replay. Those are not the same. `nonce` is not part of EIP-712 as far as I can tell, but I agree that relying only on chainID for such cases seems unsecure.

Comment: There are protocols (DApp) that are running on several EVM compatible chains, in that case, adding a chainID domain separator is an additional security that makes sense.

Comment: 'that's not necessarily true' hello, we are talking about signatures conforming to the EIP155 standard, so that is true, the signed message would include the v (the chainID) info. If you sign a transaction including a message that I signed, and the message I signed would include the chainID info as the v parameter.

Comment: "EIP-155 protects against tx replay“ that's by including the chainID info in the signature. "EIP-712 protects against message replay" but the chainID in EIP-712 message wouldn't add any extra protection if the signed message already uses EIP-155, which most signed messages do today.

Comment: "nonce is not part of EIP-712", it is not, it's included in OpenZepplin's contracts for things like Permit or etc (signed message), that's the thing that prevents replays to the same application, not the chainID.

Comment: "an additional security that makes sense" no the chainID is already in the EIP-155 compatible signed message, hashing it twice wouldn't make it any secure, the current hash collision algorithm would find any attack vector either way.

Comment: "hello, we are talking about signatures conforming to the EIP155 standard, so that is true, the signed message would include the v (the chainID) info." , can you show me where EIP-712 says that it conforms to the EIP-155 standard ? does it take a from , to , value , etc.. parameter ? no it doesn't, because it is not intended to sign transactions, it is a standard for signed messages that are not transactions.

Comment: From EIP-712 : "This EIP aims to improve the usability of off-chain message signing for use on-chain. We are seeing growing adoption of off-chain message signing as it saves gas and reduces the number of transactions on the blockchain." it is pretty clear that EIP-712 goal is different than EIP-155.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134755/discussion-between-hroussille-and-frt132).